# How to Download maven jars and its dependencies from both default central maven & other public repos?

Tags: java, maven

I am looking to download Atlassian jar and its dependencies, (which exist in different repos https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/)

I am trying to download 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.jira/jira-rest-java-client-core/5.0.4

With pom.xml file extracted from the above jar file

I am using Apache Maven 3.6.3

So far I have tried below commands by looking at various SO links

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory="D:\pom\jira\output"

mvn -DrepoUrl="https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/" -DgroupId=com.atlassian.jira -DartifactId=jira-rest-java-client-api -Dversion=5.1.6 dependency:copy-dependencies


mvn -DoutputDirectory="D:\pom\jira\output" -DrepoUrl="https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/"  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get -DgroupId=com.atlassian.jira -DartifactId=jira-rest-java-client-api -Dversion=5.1.6


mvn -DoutputDirectory="D:\pom\jira\output" -DrepoUrl="https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/"  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get dependency:get -DgroupId=com.atlassian.jira -DartifactId=jira-rest-java-client-api -Dversion=5.1.6
```

I believe errors are just suggesting, it can't find the Atlassian lib in default central apache maven2 repo.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I would configure the repositories in the `settings.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is 2 ways to do it :

1) Specify in your Project **pom.xml** which repositories you want to use :

```
<project>
...
...
  <repositories>

    <repository>
      <id>repo1</id>
      <name>your custom Repo1</name>
      <url>your repo1 url</url>
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>repo2</id>
      <name>your custom Repo2</name>
      <url>your repo2 url</url>
    </repository>

  </repositories>
...
...
</project>
```

2) Creating a profile in your maven setting file 
**${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml**

(*if you have downloaded version of maven you should edit in : **your_custom_maven_unzipped_folder/conf/settings.xml*** )

```
    <settings>
   ...
   <profiles>
      ...
      <profile>
         <id>myprofile</id>
         <repositories>
            <repository>
               <id>repo1</id>
               <name>your custom Repo1</name>
               <url>your repo1 url</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
               <id>repo2</id>
               <name>your custom Repo2</name>
               <url>your repo2 url</url>
            </repository>
         </repositories>
      </profile>
      ...
   </profiles>
   <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>myprofile</activeProfile>
   </activeProfiles>
   ...
</settings>
```